# How to show the place and only the words found Findstr?

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I wonder how do I show the location where the words were found in findstr?

**My Code:**

```
Set "LFiles=%temp%\Files\*.txt">nul 2>&1

Findstr /li /G:"List.txt" "%LFiles%">"Result.TxT"

(for /F %%a in (List.txt) do (
   Findstr /li /C:"%%a" "%LFiles%" > NUL
   if not errorlevel 1 echo %%a
))>"Result2.TxT"
```

**List:**

```
Disc
Music
Song
Album
```

**Result:**

```
DISC1312we7das67da
13dsdsa67dsahdsa7aMUSIC
dsadsdfdsaSONG1223234235
```

**Result2:**

```
Disc
Music
Song
```

**The desired result in Result2:**

```
--------------
Filelist1.txt
--------------
Song

--------------
Filelist2.txt
--------------
Song
Disc

--------------
Filelist3.txt
--------------
Disc
Music
Song
```

**Note:** the filenames are random

**@Edit**

I could make him show you what was found in each file...

Came here two problems:

1. How do I show him the file names if they have spaces in the name?
2. How do I join the results of the same file on a single line?

.

```
Dir /b "%temp%\Files\*.txt">Files2.txt

Set "LFiles=LFiles=%temp%\Files\*.txt">nul 2>&1

Findstr /li /G:"List.txt" "%LFiles%">"Result.TxT"

(for /F %%a in (Files2.txt) do (
(for /F %%b in (List.txt) do (
   Findstr /li /C:"%%b" "Result.txt" > NUL
   if not errorlevel 1 echo "%%a" "%%b"
))))>>"Result2.TxT"
```

**Current result:**

```
"File" "Disc"
"File" "Song"
"File" "Music"
"Files_and" "Disc"
```

**The desired result**

```
File 01.txt: Song, Music
File 02.txt: Music, Disc
```

or

```
File 01.txt:
Song
Music

File 02.txt:
Music
Disc
```

Comment: Don't use `%Path%` as a user variable.  Clobbering it is bad practice.  Are you trying to determine which files in `%temp%\Files\*.txt` match each line of `list.txt`?  Does it get you closer to your desired output if you remove `>NUL` and `if not errorlevel 1 echo %%a`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the variable path is that I made a literal translation of the original term (I have changed the post). The if "if not errorlevel 1 echo %%a" I'm using to get the exact words, I say this' cause this in the middle of several characters...

Comment: I see what it does.  You can actually combine those two lines using [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) like this: `Findstr /li /C:"%%a" "%LFiles%" >NUL && echo %%a`.  But what I'm saying is `findstr search *wildcard*` will output not only the matching line, but also the filename in which the string was found.  Maybe redirecting its output to `>NUL` is doing more harm than good.

Comment: I made some changes but still can not do the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below execute `findstr` command just one time per each word in List.txt file, so it should run faster. It also keep the results in "file" array for any further processing:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "LFiles=%temp%\Files\*.txt"

for /F %%a in (List.txt) do (
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('findstr /LIM /C:"%%a" "%LFiles%"') do (
      set "file[%%~Nb]=!file[%%~Nb]! %%a"
      set /A "word[%%a]+=1"
   )
)

(for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set file[') do (
   echo --------------
   echo %%a.txt
   echo --------------
   for %%c in (%%b) do echo %%c
   echo/
)) > Result2.txt

ECHO RESULT IN REQUESTED FORMAT:
TYPE RESULT2.TXT
ECHO/
ECHO/
ECHO VALUES STORED IN "FILE" ARRAY:
SET FILE[

ECHO WORD COUNT:
SET WORD[
```

**EDIT**: New method that count the number of each word per file, as requested in comment.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "LFiles=%temp%\Files\*.txt"

rem Accumulate counts of all file/word combinations in a two-dimensional array
for /F %%a in (List.txt) do (
   for /F "delims=:" %%b in ('findstr /LI /C:"%%a" "%LFiles%"') do (
      set /A "count[%%~Nb][%%a]+=1"
   )
)

rem Group word counts for the same file
for /F "tokens=2,3* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   set "file[%%a]=!file[%%a]!, %%b (%%c)"
)

rem Show the final result
(for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set file[') do (
   set "line=%%b"
   echo %%a.txt = !line:~2!
)) > Result2.TxT


ECHO THE COUNT ARRAY:
SET COUNT[
ECHO/
ECHO THE FILE ARRAY:
SET FILE[
```

This new method count the number of matching *lines* in each file. If the same word may appear two or more times in a line, it will be counted just as one. This point may be fixed in order to count *individual words*, but the resulting code will be much slower...

Comment: So, first thanks for the help, but the way you had not showing correctly the result may be the name of files or language from my computer...

Image: http://i.imgur.com/tQxkmp5.png

Comment: Ops! I had a small bug! (the`/F` switch missing in the first `for /F %%a ...`). Please, fix it and test the code again...

Comment: Now is working perfectly, just two more questions like do to show this way ... In fileX found CD (10) and fileY found CD (5)...

In practice as:

`[Test.txt]= CD (10), Music (5)` `[Test2.txt]= CD (3), Music (4)`

| Note: Still keeping the total |

and how you would separate with commas if you have more than one element.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your last request. Could you include a clearer example in the original question? **NOTE**: my solution does NOT count _individual words_, just if a word appear in the file. If you want the count of how many words were found in each file, then I suggest you to open a new question and be very clear about this point.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm asking above the original. I will open another question as suggested.

Comment: I developed a solution for your new request, but you take too long to post the new question! See the edit in this answer...

Comment: I'm sorry, these two days were very run and was almost no time for anything... anyway thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "LFiles=%temp%\Files\*.txt"
(
for %%i in ("%LFiles%") do (
  set "result="
  for /f %%j in (list.txt) do (
    findstr /li /c:"%%j" "%%~i">nul && set result=!result!, %%j
  )
  if defined result echo %%i:!result:~1!
)
)>result.txt
```

Comment: Please how do I leave just the file name without the path and extension?

Comment: instead of `echo %%i` use `echo %%~ni `.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you could answer me one more question? I have a word counter the problem is that I could not put the same word to appear side showing the amount of time she was found in the file... code: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript /nologo CountWords.vbs "%%j" "%%~i"') do Echo %%a` something like: Disc (5), Music (10).

Comment: @HumbertoFreitas: I just added such feature to [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847971/how-to-show-the-place-and-only-the-words-found-findstr/30851361#30851361)...